# Google Maps Custom Projection

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-2, map-projections

I have created a custom Google Maps projection using the Google Maps Javascript API V2.  It looks like this, as per the API specification:

```
function PProjection(levels) {

 this.fromLatLngToPixel = function(latlng, zoom) {
  ...
 };

 this.fromPixelToLatLng = function(pixel, zoom) {
  ...
 };

 this.tileCheckRange = function(tile, zoom, tilesize) {
  ...
 };

 this.getWrapWidth = function(zoom) {
  ...
 };
}
```

Previously, I had my version of the API set to 2.147 and everything worked fine.  However, Google recently made the lowest version available 2.193.  This new version breaks my projection.  Whenever I try to add a marker, I get the following error in Firebug:

*d.getNearestImage is not a function*

According to [this](http://groups.google.vu/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/56bda2c00ecfa2b0) post a new method called

```
GProjection.getNearestImage(pixel,zoom,centrepixel)
```

was added in version 2.148, so it kind of makes sense that this problem would occur if I used a version of the API above 2.147.  However, there is no note in the reference manual of an official change in the API.  I added a dummy method of this name to my projection, but no luck.  Any ideas on how to fix my projection or on how to revert to 2.147?

Answer (score 0):

You can request a specific version through this method: http://groups-beta.google.com/group/google-maps-api/web/javascript-maps-api-versioning

Comment: Yes, that is what I was doing before, but unfortunately all versions less than 2.193 have been discontinued.  Therefore, even if I specify version 2.147, I get 2.193.